# How to call Google App Script from a web app?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Task:** Open a google spreadsheet in web app, select a portion of values in that spreadsheet and on clicking a button on my web app, I should get selected values.

I tried to this through Google App script (following code). This works fine when I run the script from online having spreadsheet opened in another tab.

```
      function doGet() 
      {
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        var data = sheet.getActiveRange().getValues();
        //Logger.log(data.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
        {
          var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Product name: " + data[i][0] + ", Quantity:" + data[i][1]);  
        }

       //Logger.log(output.getContent());
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(output);
      };
```

But when I try to deploy the script as web app and take the published url as the action for my form when I click button in my web app. Its not working.

```
  <form action="https://script.google.com/macros/...." method="get">
<input type="submit" value="call">
  </form>
```

I added the above code in my webapp, where the spreadsheet is opened and displayed!

Now, when I click the "call" button from my web app it throws error "TypeError: Cannot call method "getActiveRange" of null."

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

These lines have meaning when you're running the script within a spreadsheet:

```
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var data = sheet.getActiveRange().getValues();
```

...but they don't when run from a web app. There's no "active sheet" or "active range" in that case.

You will need to express those as:

```
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('--ss_id--').openSheetByName('--sheet-name--');
    var data = sheet.getRange(--Some-range-expression--).getValues();
```

... or a variation of that.

You cannot interact between a user in the spreadsheet and the web app, to pass the selected cells, for instance. You will need to re-think your task. For instance, you could select the cells in the sheet & make them a named range that is served via web app. Or you could add a menu item to create the named range.